# How can I implement header view + sliding pager tab strip + view pager like Fancy app?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-view

I'm curious how Fancy(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thefancy.app) implements this kind of view. Images at the below are captured on seller page of Fancy app.

At first, it has header view + sliding tab strip + view pager which contains fragments.
If user scrolling down the view, the header view will be disappeared smoothly, and then finally user can only see pager title and view pager.

I'm trying to implement similar feature using `PagerSlidingTabStrip`(https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) and `ViewPager` with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` contains few fragments that using `StaggeredGridView` by Etsy. (https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid)

To implement this feature, I assume that I have to use `OnScrollListener` of `StaggeredGridView`, but there's few problem.

The first one is how to delivery the scrolling event to main activity.
The process of transmission of scrolling event is: 
`StaggeredGridView` -> `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` -> `MainActivity`. 
It is a long way to make it has smooth scrolling. Also, I cannot sure the parameters from scroll event are sufficient to implement this.

```
public void onScroll(final AbsListView view, final int firstVisibleItem, 
        final int visibleItemCount, final int totalItemCount) {
```

(`onScroll` only have value of index of first visible item, the number of visible item, and the total count of item.)

There is other way to handle event between many fragments and activities using event bus library like `otto` by square (https://github.com/square/otto), but also I don't think it's a good idea.

I found a blog post that is helpful to implement pretty action bar + listview (http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2013/11/20/making-your-action-bar-not-boring/) but still have no idea how to implement view like Fancy.

Probably, do I need to create custom view pager which detects scrolling event easily? Or, are there any beautiful open source or helpful tips? Little hint can be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

[image: At the first time]

[image: Slide down]

[image: When sliding is finished]

Comment: FYI. This library will be helpful. (https://github.com/kmshack/Android-ParallaxHeaderViewPager)

Comment: Note that view like Fancy is possible using the link I mention above, but I still have struggle with implementing the view with SGV instead of ListView.